# Compute 2 Columns from current row and from the row above

Tags: mysql, sql, select, window-functions

I have a table that looks like this

[image: Current Output]

My target is to look like this

[image: Expected Outout]

Basically what it did is to sum all the way down based on stock in and stock out from beginning balance however I cant achieve it. How can I display this?

I hope my table will display balance without affecting the Beginning balance row

Comment: 1) No ordering - no result. Remember - physical ordering in the output is not applicable. 2) When you'll define rows ordering - use LAG() function.

Comment: i have a primary id AI, i just didnt add it on my example

Comment: If so then use `LAG()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions (if you are running MySQL 8.0). Assuming that colum `id` defines the ordering of rows, that would be:

```
select
    t.*,
    sum(coalesce(balance, 0) + coalesce(stock_in, 0) - coalesce(stock_out, 0))
        over(partition by branch_id order by id) new_balance
from mytable t
```

Comment: does it affect my report if i have 2 branch id?

Comment: @PaulEdwardPagente: the sum is partitioned by `branch_id`, so this will work regardless of how many `branch_id`s you have.

Comment: tysm for this answer